# CSS h2 tag with different colors and classes?

Tags: css

i have couple h2 tags, where i want some, to have the same formatting, but to be of a different color

```
h2
{
    font: bold 20px "TitilliumMedium", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #1f1d5b;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1f1d5b;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.red h2
{
    color: #551111;
}
```

the two below look exactly the same? did i do something wrong? should i just use font color tags around the h2?

```
  <h2>test</h2>
    <h2 class='red'>test2</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
.red{color: #551111;}
```

`.red h2` means an element with class `red` having child element `h2`.

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQNt4/)

Comment: Or... a `h2` element having a parent of class `red`.

Comment: Or better use id's. In case of similar elements, it helps a lots to use id's.

Answer (score 1):

You can target only h2 tags with the red class by:

```
h2.red {
  color: #551111;
}
```

In your current css definition, you will be targeting the h2 tag inside an element with the class "red", i.e:

```
<div class="red">
  <h2>Red Text</h2>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `h2.red` (no space between them) which means 'H2 with class red'